# Admob house ad not display in my iPhone device

Tags: ios, admob

Hi i have create one admob application and write his Publisher id in my code. And now the admob display the advertise. And after that i have create one house ad for display my add in my device. so i follow this steps

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/1619751?hl=en

and Run the Application but i have not showing any add that i have created. I have changed the testing mode off in my application. please help me.

Comment: did you set in code request.testing = YES;

Comment: @ Nitin Gohel no i have set request.testing=NO.

Comment: For testing you need to set YES and when you going to upload binary in to app store put NO before upload it

Comment: @ Nitin Gohel  yes i know this but now i want to customize the advertisment like i want to add my company's add so i just created the house add and checked in my device but no ad display.

Comment: I think best way to handle these situation is #define in your debug configuration say DEBUG=1 and then write code like this #ifdefine DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck solving this problem by going to iOS Settings / Privacy / Advertising and then selecting "Reset Advertising Identifier..."

I wanted to wait until I could verify this solution before posting an answer here.  So I just ran into the problem again where AdMob was refusing to serve me my house ad, and when I reset the device's advertising identified, I was then able to get the House Ad.